# jquery select single tag class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

seems a little trivial but am having a hard time solving it, i have a jquery function to select the class of a tag on click but the problem is that it selects every other tag underneath the tag clicked as well in structural order where as i only want the very first one

for example if i have

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
      <div class="3">
          <p class="4">Hello World</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and i clicked on the (p) tag that says hello world i would get an alert 
saying 4 then 3 then 2 then 1
but like i said i only want the first one witch in this case is 4

here is my jquery code

```
$("*").dblclick(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("") && !$(this).hasClass("main")){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    }
});
```

i know the problem is happening because technically i am clicking all of the tags so it continus to loop trough but i still need a way to break it after the first class is selected or better yet is there a way to select only the topmost object

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false;` from event handler

Comment: Just read about `event bubbling` and `event capturing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add return to the function like so:

```
$("*").dblclick(function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass("") && !$(this).hasClass("main")){
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Small Case `return false;`

Comment: dude thanks your a life saver such a tiny problem but its taken me the better part of a day

Comment: May I ask though why you are selecting all classes? Let me post a more efficient answer example, based on the given logic, unless htis was just for demo reasons.

Comment: It won't let me post an answer, but just select by the class main, the rest is not necessary

Comment: example: $("*").not(".main").dbclick(function(){alert($(this).class());});

Comment: or even better: $("*").not(".main").first().dbclick(function(){alert($(this).class());});

Answer (score 1):

I would pass in event to your click function, and after you've finished your logic, use event.stopPropagation(). This prevents the event from bubbling up to parent elements

```
$("*").dblclick(function(event){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("") && !$(this).hasClass("main")){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: `!$(this).hasClass("")` not required

Comment: this is also a good solution. I will give this an answer point.

Answer (score 0):

Run this example and look your console.

```js
$("body > div").dblclick(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
      <div class="3">
          <p class="4">Hello World</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `event bubbling` and `event propagation`.

Here is function which does what you want:

```
$("*").dblclick(function(e){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("") && !$(this).hasClass("main")){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

And here is working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/18sawk57/

Although it's not a good solution to attach event listening to all of the tags on the page. Much better solution is to add for example `id` or `clickable class attribute` for elements that should have event listening.

Here is another working example with better approach: https://jsfiddle.net/tr7aqask/

Here is another working example with bubbling disabled using jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/yc0481sm/